# .Net HTML Editor Control

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-3.5, wysiwyg

I need to add in a WYSIWYG control into a .NET form. I found this one from SpiceLogic on several sites and was wondering if this is a decent library to use?

http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/NET-Win-HTML-Editor-Control-8/

If anyone has any additional input, I also would like to know of any other decent alternatives, both free and non-free.

Thanks in advance for any opinions on this!

*EDIT* Should have clarified this before, but this is a desktop application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try one of these strategies:

1. Use the RichTextBox control, which exposes a FlowDocument. Write a program that converts the FlowDocument to HTML. Since FlowDocs are much more constrained that HTML, this conversion might be pretty straightforward (sections -> div, paragraph -> p, styles -> css or style attributes, etc).
2. Use MSHTML and put it into edit mode. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753622(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: We ended up going with your second suggestion, better than spending money when we have tools to get it done natively.

Comment: The best thing is it's free :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [XStandard](http://www.xstandard.com/). I have used it in CMS web sites and it works great. You can also use it with desktop apps. There is a free "lite" version and a for=pay pro version. It creates XHTML markup and has lots of slick built-in functionality.

As a comparison, I have used Telerik RAD Editor and XStandard is much better (IMO). I have also tried other web-specific solutions like FCKEditor and TinyMCE and I prefer XStandard.

Comment: XStandard seems pretty nice, the only issue is that while we currently are a 32-bit app, we are looking to move to 64-bit within the next year or so and XStandard "as of now" is 32-bit only.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is to get XHTML all the time right from the beginning which should be published on the Web, then, I would say, "Yes", you can try that component from SpiceLogic, especially the version 5.x which was released very recently. It comes with many features like embedding images for an email client, Uploading local images to FTP, paste from MS Word, rich Dialogs for Tables, Images, Hyperlink, Symbols, Inline Spell Checker and Spell Checker dialogs, and more.

https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/NET-WinForms-HTML-Editor-Control-8

[image: features]

All Screenshots:

http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/NET-WinForms-HTML-Editor-Control-8/Screenshots

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE is a great way to achieve this. Here is a way to embed TinyMCE in Winform. I tested it and it works pretty well: https://github.com/Rocker93/winforms-html-editor

An other solution is [CEFSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/). The integration is not easy but it's very well documented and it's the most powerful and free solution I have found.

Answer (score 0):

At work we use telerik controls for this stuff:
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx

its definitely not free though.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, this is going into a desktop application, not a web app.